# How do I setup sqlsvr in PHP 8.1 and above?

Tags: php, sql-server

Currently I have PHP 8.1.14,and right now when I try to use sqlsrv_connect() it will only show me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().
```

After some researching I realized that I need to download some extensions for my PHP in order to use it.

The two .dll I've downloaded are and placed in my **C:\xampp\php\ext** folder are:

**php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll** and **php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll**

Which I am not certain if I have downloaded the correct one.

I have also added these extensions in the **php.ini** file under the **Dynamic Extension** section.

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
```

Also, these are the line of codes that i used to call sqlsvr_connect() function

```
<?php
   $serverName = " **server name**, **Port Number**"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"**Database**", "UID"=>"**user ID**", "PWD"=>"**Password**");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

            if( $conn ) {
                 echo "Connection established.<br />";
            }else{
                 echo "<script>alert('Could not establish connection!');
                    ";
                    die("window.history.go(-1);</script>");
                }
            
?>
```

Would highly appreciate any help regarding this matter! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the extension folder is located at `C:\xampp\php\ext`? If you open a PowerShell window and execute `php -i | sls extension_dir` what is the result? Is there a line in your `php.ini` file along the lines of `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"` (or wherever the above command reported it to be)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, I have checked my php.ini file and it says `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`

Comment: If you run `phpinfo();` can you see `sqlsrv` or `pdo_sqlsrv` listed in the ouput? Is it 64 bit php? Usually if the bit version and php version match the sqlsrv extension you should be okay. IIS requires the `nts` version, but `ts` might be correct for apache. Are there any errors in the webserver startup logs?

Comment: There is a seperate `Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server` package you might need to download and install from the Microsoft Website.

Comment: `sqlite` is a different database system. You won't need it enabled in the ini file to connect to MS SQL server.

Comment: @DuckDensity Yes, i can see sqlsrv at the Registered PHP streams, PDO section, pdo_sqlsrv section